# Free space on the top menu, as it removed?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the top menu "My quotes ..." on all sides is displayed free space as its clean and completely fill the entire top?

**HTML**

```
        <ul class="topPanel">
        <li><h2>My Quotes</h2></li>
        <li><h2>LOGIN WITH 
          <a href="#" class="underline">EMAIL</a> 
          OR 
          <a href="#" class="underline">TWITTER</a>
          </h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    <!-- /*Main settings, background*/ -->
html {
    background: url(http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Rainbow-lanscape-nature-scenery-images-new-desktop-hd-wallpapers-landscape-widescreen.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
 }
<!-- /*top panel contains a name for the project from the left side and the 
ability to login via twitter and email*/ -->
.topPanel {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;

    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;

    padding:0px;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
    .topPanel li {
        margin: auto;
    }
        .topPanel li h2 {
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin: 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /*Change the color of links when you hover*/
        .underline {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: underline;

            transition:color 1s;
            -webkit-transition:color 1s; 
        }
            .underline:hover {
                color: #eb005f;
            }
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .topPanel {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .topPanel {
        -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    }
}
```

`Margin: 0` does not work. I noticed that sometimes the space is not shown that it can be?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox, the same situation with incorrect display. [Visually, you can see here.](http://codepen.io/rubinchyk/pen/kFqca)

Comment: That's the default margin on the `body` element.. use `body {margin:0}`

Comment: It's very difficult to decode your english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the default `body` margin and padding

```
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ysIEr)